# How to pass variable inside the ssh command inside for loop

Tags: linux, shell, ssh

I have a VM where I have a folder **A** which contains `doc1.txt` `doc2.txt` `king1.so` and `king2.so`
I am trying to list the files of a specific extension using `ssh` from another VM.

```
VAR_PATH="/predefined/path/to/A"
echo $VAR_PATH

for file_path in `ssh user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx "find $VAR_PATH -iname "*.so""`
do
        echo $file_path
done
```

This is not working and giving me error as

> find: paths must precede expression: sample.so
> Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]

the same command works when I am ***hardcoding the path*** in `find` command

```
for file_path in `ssh user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx "find /predefined/path/to/A -iname "*.so""`
do
        echo $file_path
done
```

How do I pass path variable inside the ssh command inside this for loop?

Comment: Quick note -- you _really_ don't want to use backticks here; they change the way other backticks and backslashes behave inside them. `$( )` is the modern way to do command substitution, and it's been standardized since the early 1990s so there's _really_ no excuse.

Comment: Anyhow -- I'm more worried about the `*.so` in your code. The double quotes are getting lost before it reaches the remote server. Make it `"set -x; find ..."` and you'll be able to see how the server is interpreting the command it receives.

Comment: (though the quotes-getting-lost isn't a remote-server problem; it's a local-parsing problem: `"foo""bar"` is _exactly_ the same as `"foobar"` -- the paired double quotes just cancel each other out; it's not like some other languages where they translate to just one literal quote).

Comment: Also, `for file_path in $(anything)` is an antipattern as a whole. See [BashPitfalls #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29); the right way to read a stream line-by-line is documented in [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001), and caveats around how to feed output from a command like `ssh` into such a loop are covered in [BashFAQ #24](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).

Comment: Unless there is more to the body of the loop, you don't it at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one: (centos 8 test passed)

```
D=/tmp/test/ && for i in `ssh xxx@xxxxx "find $D -name '*.so'"`;do echo $i;done
```

Answer (score -2):

Better to do without the for-loop and store the output in an array, then you can loop or anything you want.

```
array_result=(`ssh user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx "find ${VAR_PATH} -iname *.so"`)
```

Comment: `array_result` isn't an array, it's a string. (Also, the `ls` command is not equivalent to the `find` it replaces -- the latter recurses, f/e).

Comment: That's not an array; it's just a single newline-delimited string.